# Is it possible to automatically sync existing (and new) android contacts with office365?

Tags: outlook.com

**Scenario:** After meeting a new acquaintance, we exchange our contact details (phone number, email ..etc). These get saved using the default contact application on an android phone. Later, when logging into my office365 account via a desktop web-browser, the new contact is not present in the address book! Checking the phone shows that it has been saved on the device. The official Outlook app from Microsoft has been installed on the android phone and is capable of sending/receiving email.

Why did the contact not sync up? Is there anything that can be done to make the contact sync happen automatically?

Am open to the idea of switching to a different android email app to get things working, but would ideally prefer to keep using Outlook (or at least a non-Google contacts/calendar/email app!).

If it matters: I have administrative access over the phone as well as the office365 account in question.

Comment: In Outook settings -> your mail@office365.com, is "Sunc contacts" enabled?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio yes, the option 'sync contacts' is enabled, but it does not appear to do anything. :(